# laravel 5.2 authentication - Missing Links

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am new to laravel framework and trying to build up authentication for a website. There is something really strange thats happening and I am not able to figure out whats wrong.

I issue php artisan make:auth command and I could see the corresponding files getting generated under controllers and the resources/views. I am able to login and see the homepage (after login). I am able to logout as well and everything works smoothly so far.

now sometimes there seems to be a problem when I am away from the browser for sometime, and come back to the website, it starts acting wierd. the app loses the information about the current logged in user. If I go to the home page (the actual homepage of the website and not the page after the login), then the login page ("/login") does not show up. I have to manually logout (by typing "/logout" in the url) and then try the login url to see the login form.

this is my routes file:

```
Route::get("/", "PagesController@home")->name("home");
Route::get("/search/{query}","APIController@index")->name("search");
Route::get("/searchBook/{id}","APIController@searchBook")->name("searchBook");
Route::get("/stories","PagesController@stories")->name("stories");
Route::get("/user/{id}/deleteBooks/{book_id}","UserController@deleteBooks")->name('user.delete.books');
Route::get("/user/{id}/showBooks/{book_id}","UserController@showBooks")->name('user.show.books');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
    Route::get('/user/{user}/books',"UserController@books")->name('user.get.books');
    Route::post("/user/{user}/createBooks","UserController@createBooks")->name('user.create.books');
    Route::get('/home', 'PagesController@dashboard')->name("dashboard");
    Route::post("/savemap","UserController@savemap")->name("savemap");
});
```

Also, It seems the app in itself is not really taking care of the authentication. I manually have to check the authentication (by Auth::check()) at lot of steps and it is painful. For example at many places I have to manually do

```
if (Auth::check()) {
        // some code
    }
    else{
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('home'); //named route
    }
```

This is an update : A route which was giving me issues was not placed under the web middleware in the routes.php file. So when I placed the concerned route under the web middleware, I was actually able to access all the Auth:: parameters and the current logged in user.

Does this mean that I have to place all my "logged-in" routes (available routes after logging in) inside the web middleware? and what about the /login, /logout routes... Should they be places any middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any route you need sessions (which Auth uses) needs to have the '**web**' middleware group applied.

If you want to do auth checks you can use the 'auth' middleware which will do those checks for you.

Example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function() {
    Route::get('mustbeauthed', 'SomeController@someMethod');
});
```

In this case going to the 'mustbeauthed' will redirect you away if you are not authenticated and let you pass through to it if you are authenticated.